# Does different percentage chocolate set differently?

Tags: chocolate, tempering, glaze

My glaze did not come out as expected. Will chocolate set differently if I start with, say 60% vs 70% chocolate? If so, is there a suggestion as to how to adjust the recipe so a lower or higher percentage chocolate will work best in a glaze?

Comment: Could you please add your recipe?

Comment: 4 oz bittersweet chocolate (55%-65%), chopped
1/2 cup heavy cream
1 Tbsp light corn syrup

In a small saucepan, bring the heavy cream just to a simmer or microwave it in a bowl.  Take off heat.  Add the chocolate and syrup and let sit for 5 minutes.  Whisk until smooth.  Make this right before using since it's not easy to reheat.  If you do have leftover ganache, warm it up over a bowl of hot water whisking constantly.

Answer (score 1):

For glazing the best is to use a couverture chocolate which is richer in cocoa butter than the standard chocolat (more than 31% for dark chocolate): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couverture_chocolate

But generally you can't find it in supermarket and you will need to buy or order in from a specialized shop. And when you check the nutritional informations, a lot of chocolates we find supermarkets will also have a cocoa butter percentage higher than 31%! The problem with these is that they are often the low quality chocolates, and their taste won't be so great and have a negative impact on the final taste of your cake...

So the best way is to try different types, ideally with the same recipe, and see which one works the best! Be patient, it took me forever to find an acceptable one... Also, make sure that your glazing recipe is good!